# How can I tranfer contacts from old Lumia 920 to new S5

Tags: data-transfer

Hi I have been able to transfer my contacts from my old Lumia 920 to my new Samsung S5 via Bluetooth, but it seems to have only copied all the old contacts. No new contacts(ones that I have added manually to the Lumia 920 over the last couple of years ) did not transfer. I suspect it only transferred what was on the SIM. But I can't figure out how to transfer from Lumia 920 back to its SIM or to the new S5??

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing your contacts with a Microsoft Account, exporting to a file, and then importing into Google Contacts. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/86153/43985) answer and [this](http://www.wintips.org/how-to-transfer-your-windows-phone-contacts-to-an-android-phone/) website.

1. Sync Microsoft Account with the Lumia
2. Export contacts from the People app in Outlook online
3. Import the contacts into Google Contacts

Comment: Can you please include the important parts from the links you provided within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lumina? Im not sure if thats  windows phone or a android based one, but the best way would be (if the "Lumina" is a android operating system) use a app like:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ashk.backuptoexcel.lite

1. Install that on both android devices
2. First from the "Lumina" backup your contacts to a .vcard file to google drive or whatever cloud storage you wish (you could use bluetooth!!)
3. On the S5, use that app, or simply just tap the vcard file and if it allows you, click save in the top right corner, all your previous contacts should be saved on you new phone!!