# Can I still use live.com for my contacts 'hub' on Android?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, import, windows-mobile, oneplus-3

I'm switching from a Lumia 1020 (Windows Phone 8.1) to a OnePlus3 (Android M I think).
I bought into the MS live.com setup for contacts so all my contact phone numbers and addresses and facebook maappings are there, *however* I also have a gmail account which is where all my email contacts are stored.

I'm worried it's all going to be a big mess, I read this already: [Switching contacts from Windows Phone to Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86105/switching-contacts-from-windows-phone-to-android?newreg=83cc95385d554764b7739e9dfdefe9b0)

I did wonder though, do I have to use Google for my contacts on Android or can I continue with Live.com? Maybe that sounds a stupid idea (I'm new to android) but I do use OneNote extensively as well as Google Drive and Gmail so I have a foot in both camps.

Is a manual dump of contacts the best way to go in 2016? I was rather expecting my new phone would let me sign into my live.com account and slurp all the contacts!

Comment: I cannot say for live.com – but nobody forces you to use Google for your contacts. I for example don't use the Google storage either (but my own cloud storage, sync'd via CardDAV). If live.com has its own app to sync contacts (or offers doing so via CardDAV), this should be possible.